# run database sql query from php just like from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Does anyone here have a ready made PHP file (script) which can connect to the database *(by inserting, host,dabasename,user,pas)* and then be used to run SQL queries. For example by putting the query in a variable and then run it. This would be the same kind of queries which can be run from phpmyadmin.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=run+sql+queries+from+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to use a MySQL database in PHP, I suggest learning about PDO:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost,dbname=YourDatabase","Username","Password");
?>
```

and submitting would go as follow:

```
<?php
    //Unsafe
        $unsafeSubmit = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES(`id`,'".$variable1."','".$variable2."')");
    //Safe
        $submitInformation = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES(`id`,:varOne,:varTwo)");
        $submitInformation->bindValue(":varOne",$variable1);
        $submitInformation->bindValue(":varTwo",$variable2);
        $submitInformation->execute();
?>
```

With reading it with the `SELECT` query.

[I suggest reading the documentation on PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on how to do this, there are multiple ways like PDO or MySQLi

[documentation mysqli on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[documentation pdo on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

These are two very well used, well supported and built in libraries in PHP which will allow you to execute queries from PHP. It's one of the first things I learned at school (deprecated mysql) so you should be fine reading up on those two.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a quick solution using Sidney Liebrand links. Thanks

```
   <?php 
    $user="username";
    $password="password";
    $database="database";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $query= /* query */ "";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Make sure you escape your variables and all. I really recommend using PDO because it makes it a whole lot easier. Also, you can use the "Add comment" button next time.

Comment: try to avoid using the deprecated mysql_* functions, mysqli is the new standard.